# Tomcat logout another user as admin

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, admin, logout

Is there a way for me as an administrator of a web application to programatically <strike>manually</strike>  disable another user's session (log him out)?

I'm using Tomcat web server and Spring MVC.

Answer (score 2):

You can login to the **Tomcat Web Application Manager** (usually under `/manager/html` path), find the row for the webapp in question, click on the number indicating number of sessions. Find the session for the user you want to logout and Invalidate that session.

Comment: Ok, my fault, I want to do it programatically, within the application (as an option on the admin panel)